# Can sociolinguistic research contribute in solving L2 learning problem?

Tags: sociolinguistics

I want to write my thesis sociolinguistically about a new linguistic phenomenon, but the main contribution to my study is to solve speaking anxiety.. my thesis will include a question, after explaining the phenomenon from the sociolinguistic perspective, about "how this phenomenon solve the problem of anxiety">...
*MY QUESTION IS: does this type of research refer to sociolinguistics or to Language learning and teaching????

Comment: There are lots of variables we don't know from your couple of sentences... Can you provide some ideas of the factors you're considering? The topic could easily touch on sociolinguistics, language acquisition, psycholinguistics, pragmatics, etc. depending on what aspect you want to look at.

Comment: Thank you so much for your attention to my question... what I am investigating is code switching ( How & Why).. in addition to theoretical problem that I found in this topic, I want to investigate its role to decrease language use anxiety... So do you think it is a sociolinguistic study by this way

Comment: Whose works are you citing? What methodology are you adopting? Are you doing a meta-analysis or an experiment? The information you've provided so far is too scant to warrant an answer.

Comment: There is the concept of linguistic insecurity in sociolinguistic (see Labov 1972).

Answer (score 1):

Following your comments: Code-switching can absolutely be construed as a sociolinguistics phenomenon and there are possible links to decreasing anxiety.

In particular, perceptions of code-switching have undergone a profound shift in the last 40 years. It used to be considered substandard — a term you should have no difficulty associating with sociolinguistics concepts such as the effects of class, ethnicity, affluence, and so on. But more recently, a partly empirical, partly theoretical shift has led to its being considered normal multilingual behaviour (keyword: compound bilingualism).

There is indeed considerable overlap with second language acquisition, and especially with learning English as a second language (TESOL), which is fraught with sociolinguistics questions such as the power dynamics of English. How do you build an immersive classroom for the target language without seeming to devalue the "underdog" native language?. In the last five years the concept of plurilingualism and translanguaging has sprung up as well and begun to erode support for monolingual classrooms.

Much more could be said, but why don't I just start you off with a few references you can branch out from. Note that since your question is not very detailed, not all may be applicable, and I don't have a lot of experience with the anxiety part especially. That said, I hope some of these will lead you down interesting paths if you follow the citations:

- Hall, G., & Cook, G. (2012). Own-language use in language teaching and learning. *Language Teaching, 45*(3), 271-308. doi:10.1017/S0261444812000067
- Kupske, F. F. (2015). Second language pedagogy and translation: The role of learners’ own-language and explicit instruction revisited. *Brazilian English Language Teaching Journal, 6*(1), 67-81.
- Liebscher, G., & Dailey-O’Cain, J. (2005). Learner code-switching in the content-based foreign language classroom. *The Modern Language Journal, 89*(2), 234-247. doi:10.1111/j.1540-4781.2005.00277.x
- Brooks-Lewis, K. (2009). Adult learners’ perceptions of the incorporation of their L1 in foreign language teaching and learning. *Applied Linguistics, 30*(2), 216-235. doi:10.1093/applin/amn051
- Piccardo, E. (2013). Plurilingualism and curriculum design: toward a synergic vision. *TESOL Quarterly, 47*, 600-614. doi:10.1002/tesq.110
- Cummins, J. (2007). Rethinking monolingual instructional strategies in multilingual classrooms. *Canadian Journal of Applied Linguistics, 10*(2), 221-240.